# SVG scripting with <symbol>

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a SVG element in JS then append it to the DOM. The SVG element references a symbol though. I can achieve this using the `insertAdjacentHTML` method but not through `appendChild` method.

When using `appendChild`, all the right stuff is on the DOM according to browser inspectors but it's not rendered correctly. Can anyone see why?

http://codepen.io/bradjohnwoods/pen/dGpqMb?editors=101

```
<svg display="none">
  <symbol id="symbol--circle--ripple" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<button id="btn">
</button>

<script>
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

//var myString = '<svg><use xlink:href="#symbol--circle--ripple" width="100" height="100" class="btn--ripple__circle"></use></svg>';
//btn.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', myString);

var svg = document.createElement('svg');
var use = document.createElement('use');
use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#symbol--circle--ripple");
use.setAttribute("width", "100");
use.setAttribute("height", "100");
use.classList.add("btn--ripple__circle");

svg.appendChild(use);
btn.appendChild(svg);
</script>
```

Comment: `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create SVG elements using `createElement`, you must use `createElementNS` to create them in the SVG namespace

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
```

`insertAdjacentHTML` invokes the html parser which magically fixes the element namespaces.

Similarly you can't use setAttribute to create attributes in the xlink namespace such as xlink:href. You want

```
setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#symbol--circle--ripple");
```

there

Comment: that does create the svg element to the correct size but doesn't instanate the symbol

Comment: xlink is deprecated in 2.0 which is widely supported today, so attributes shouldn't be NS'd. But elements must be, because this solved my problem. It's just that, if they got rid of the HTML namespace, why do we have to resort to this? Is there a global way of specifiying that the js module is meant for SVG DOM?

Comment: @Hatebit Well IE doesn't support non-namespaced href, inkscape doesn't either, nor does Batik, and I'm not so sure about Safari either, so YMMV. If you have an SVG document then I believe createElement does work (in some environments).

Comment: Right. Well, for YMMV stuff, I check out the MDN compatiblity section. IE misses so many things, I can't be bothered anymore... I can confirm that in Firefox 76, setting "href" on document.createElement('use') will not load the symbol where href=id

Comment: Yep, a document XML transformed by Xalan using xsl:output image/svg+xml method xml, loaded directly into firefox, having a script type ecmascript at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, .createElementNS & .setAttributeNS had to be used.

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
var use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#symbol--circle--ripple');
```